# Dictionnaire français vers français avec IPA

Tags: prononciation, ressources, dictionnaires

Je cherche un dictionnaire dont les lemmes comportent l'IPA. Par exemple, pour *monde*, on y trouverait :

```
"monde"  mɔ̃d   1 (= planète) le meilleur du monde
```

Pourriez-vous m'en recommander un ?

Comment: Parmi ceux qu'on peut trouver gratuitement en ligne je dirais probablement [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monde)

Comment: Pour mon information personnelle, que signifie ici IPA ?

Comment: Alphabet phonétique international / *International Phonetic Alphabet*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le Petit Robert, un dictionnaire de référence bien reconnu et estimé dans la Francophonie, inclut depuis au moins 1984 (et probablement avant) les prononciations en alphabet phonétique international, avec des mises à jour pour les mots dont la prononciation a évolué depuis l'époque.

Les prononciations sont principalement celles observées dans la région parisienne par des locuteurs cultivés, et ne recouvrent donc pas l'ensemble des prononciations observées dans l'ensemble du monde francophone, mais elles seront reconnues et acceptables (à peu près) partout, et pourront sans conteste servir de point de départ pour quelqu'un en apprentissage de la langue, quitte à ajuster légèrement avec le parler local.

Answer (score 0):

Le dictionnaire « [Antidote](https://www.antidote.info/fr/antidote) » de l'éditeur « [Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/) » comporte l'IPA et l'APF.